# Create Azure VM without have storageaccount by Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, virtual-machine, azure-storage-account

I have created VM by using ansible but when the VM is created, the storage account is also created in Azure which I don't need. Is there anyone knows how can I create VM without have storage account.

Here is my ansible code

```
- name: Create windows vms
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: "{{ RG_VMS }}"
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    vm_size: Standard_B2ms
    admin_username: user
    admin_password: "{{ password }}"
    network_interfaces: "{{ item.key }}-nic"
    os_type: Windows
    os_disk_name: disk{{ item.key }}
    os_disk_size_gb: 127
    os_disk_caching: ReadWrite
    managed_disk_type: StandardSSD_LRS
    image:
      offer: WindowsServer
      publisher: MicrosoftWindowsServer
      sku: 2016-Datacenter
      version: latest
    tags: 
      otapenvironment: "{{ OTAPENVIRONMENT }}"
      systemtype: "{{ item.value.systemtype }}"
  loop: "{{ WINDOWS_VMS | dict2items }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating Azure VM with ansible by using the below script and it got created successfully like below:-

**By default azurerm ansible provider requires storage account for storing VM's OS disk  VHD configurations, If you do not want to create a Storage account, You need to create your VM with managed disk**

> Note:- storage_account_name  Name of an existing storage account that supports creation of VHD blobs. If not specified for a new VM, a new storage account started with name will be created using storage type Standard_LRS. Only used when OS disk created with virtual hard disk  (VHD). Used when managed_disk_type not defined.

**Note Reference:-**
[azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine module – Manage Azure virtual machines — Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html)

With storage account for VHD:-

**Code:-**

```yaml
#deployWindowsAzureVirtualMachine.yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_prompt:
    - name: password
      prompt: "Enter local administrator password"

  tasks:
    - name: Create resource group
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:
        name: rg-cs-ansible
        location: eastus

    - name: Create virtual network
      azure_rm_virtualnetwork:
        resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987
        name: vnet-cs-web
        address_prefixes: "10.0.0.0/16"

    - name: Add subnet
      azure_rm_subnet:
        resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987
        name: snet-cs-web
        address_prefix: "10.0.1.0/24"
        virtual_network: vnet-cs-web

    - name: Create public IP address
      azure_rm_publicipaddress:
        resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987
        allocation_method: Static
        name: pip-cs-web
      register: output_ip_address

    - name: Output public IP
      debug:
        msg: "The public IP is {{ output_ip_address.state.ip_address }}"

    - name: Create Network Security Group
      azure_rm_securitygroup:
        resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987
        name: nsg-cs-web
        rules:
          - name: 'allow_rdp'
            protocol: Tcp
            destination_port_range: 3389
            access: Allow
            priority: 1001
            direction: Inbound
          - name: 'allow_web_traffic'
            protocol: Tcp
            destination_port_range:
              - 80
              - 443
            access: Allow
            priority: 1002
            direction: Inbound
          - name: 'allow_powershell_remoting'
            protocol: Tcp
            destination_port_range:
              - 5985
              - 5986
            access: Allow
            priority: 1003
            direction: Inbound

    - name: Create a network interface
      azure_rm_networkinterface:
        name: nic-cs-web
        resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987
        virtual_network: vnet-cs-web
        subnet_name: snet-cs-web
        security_group: nsg-cs-web
        ip_configurations:
          - name: default
            public_ip_address_name: pip-cs-web
            primary: True


    - name: Create VM
      azure_rm_virtualmachine:
        resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987
        name: vm-cs-web01
        vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2
        admin_username: azureuser
        admin_password: "{{ password }}"
        network_interfaces: nic-cs-web
        os_type: Windows
        image:
          offer: WindowsServer
          publisher: MicrosoftWindowsServer
          sku: 2019-Datacenter
          version: latest
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Storage account created for VHD :-

[image]

Without Storage account with managed disk:-

**Code:-**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

connection: local

  

vars_prompt:

- name: password

prompt: "Enter local administrator password"

  

tasks:

- name: Create resource group

azure_rm_resourcegroup:

name: rg-cs-ansible0987

location: eastus

  

- name: Create virtual network

azure_rm_virtualnetwork:

resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987

name: vnet-cs-web3

address_prefixes: "10.0.0.0/16"

  

- name: Add subnet

azure_rm_subnet:

resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987

name: snet-cs-web3

address_prefix: "10.0.1.0/24"

virtual_network: vnet-cs-web3

  

- name: Create public IP address

azure_rm_publicipaddress:

resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987

allocation_method: Static

name: pip-cs-web3

register: output_ip_address

  

- name: Output public IP

debug:

msg: "The public IP is {{ output_ip_address.state.ip_address }}"

  

- name: Create Network Security Group

azure_rm_securitygroup:

resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987

name: nsg-cs-web3

rules:

- name: 'allow_rdp'

protocol: Tcp

destination_port_range: 3389

access: Allow

priority: 1001

direction: Inbound

- name: 'allow_web_traffic'

protocol: Tcp

destination_port_range:

- 80

- 443

access: Allow

priority: 1002

direction: Inbound

- name: 'allow_powershell_remoting'

protocol: Tcp

destination_port_range:

- 5985

- 5986

access: Allow

priority: 1003

direction: Inbound

  

- name: Create a network interface

azure_rm_networkinterface:

name: nic-cs-web3

resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987

virtual_network: vnet-cs-web3

subnet_name: snet-cs-web3

security_group: nsg-cs-web3

ip_configurations:

- name: default

public_ip_address_name: pip-cs-web3

primary: True

  
  

- name: Create VM

azure_rm_virtualmachine:

resource_group: rg-cs-ansible0987

name: vm-cs-web01234

vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2

managed_disk_type: Premium_LRS

admin_username: azureuser

admin_password: "{{ password }}"

network_interfaces: nic-cs-web3

os_type: Windows

image:

offer: WindowsServer

publisher: MicrosoftWindowsServer

sku: 2019-Datacenter

version: latest
```

**Output:-**

VM managed disk is created like below without a need for storage account:-

[image]

**Reference :-**

[Deploy a Windows VM to Azure with Ansible - DEV Community](https://dev.to/cloudskills/deploy-a-windows-vm-to-azure-with-ansible-2l9m)